# UWP: Misaligned picture captured from Webcam : Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, webcam-capture

I am trying to capture pictures from a webcam on Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows IOT core. Sometimes I get misaligned pictures as shown below. I face the same problem with different webcams. The misalignment seems to be pretty random. I get a different sort of misalignment every time I capture. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code.

```
    private Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture captureManager;
    private ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat;
    private StorageFolder myPictures;

    public Camera()
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        captureManager.InitializeAsync().AsTask().Wait();
        imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        StorageLibrary pictureLibrary = Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures).AsTask().Result;
        myPictures = pictureLibrary.SaveFolder;
    }

    public StorageFile TakePictureToFile()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string foldername = now.ToString("ddMMyy");
        string filename = now.ToString("hh-mm-sstt fffffff");

        StorageFolder foldertosave = null;
        if (!Directory.Exists(myPictures.Path + "\\" + foldername))
        {
            foldertosave = myPictures.CreateFolderAsync(foldername).AsTask().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            foldertosave = myPictures.GetFolderAsync(foldername).AsTask().Result;
        }
        StorageFile file = foldertosave.CreateFileAsync(filename).AsTask().Result;

        captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file).AsTask().Wait();
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: What is your Webcam device? Here is a list of cameras supported by Windows 10 IoT Core. You may check it.